# installed flutter android studio and xcode everything working fine i can run the flutter project in android studio but cant run in xcode

Tags: android, xcode, macos, flutter, dart

Running Xcode build...
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                         3.2s
Xcode build done.                                           21.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

this is the out put of the terminal what can i do

Comment: You need to open xcode and set signature from it. Additionally, try `flutter clean` and then `flutter run` from the command line.

Comment: Bro Tamil la bro nee ga I tried everything bro flutter clean flutter run but ends with error only 

Comment: Aama bro. Have you set the correct path `export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"`? So flutter command is working?

Comment: S bro now working did flutter upgrade and as your suggestions flutter clean and flutter run followed by that